# How to disable / get rid of the Mozilla Quality Feedback program?

Tags: firefox, browser

How do I get rid of 'Mozilla Quality Feedback' program, which appears in my taskbar every time I start Firefox? Clicking on it does nothing.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Navigate to

```
C:\Program Files\Mozilla Firefox\extensions\talkback@mozilla.org\components\
```

You should see a `talkback.exe` executable, run it.

Choose Settings > Turn Agent Off.

Comment: Note - this assumes the user is running Windows - for the Mac and Linux methods of running the agent, see http://support.mozilla.com/en-US/kb/quality+feedback+agent#Turning_the_Quality_Feedback_Agent_on under "Open the Quality Feedback Agent interface".

Answer (score 2):

Copied from ["How to Disable Mozilla Crash Reporter"](http://www.askvg.com/how-to-disable-mozilla-crash-reporter-aka-breakpad-in-firefox-thunderbird-and-seamonkey/):

1. Open My computer and goto the installation directory of the application:

   - Mozilla Firefox: `%programfiles%\Mozilla Firefox`
   - Thunderbird: `%programfiles%\Mozilla Thunderbird`
   - SeaMonkey: `%programfiles%\mozilla.org\SeaMonkey`

   Here `%programfiles%` stands for `C:\Program Files` folder. Replace C: with your system drive letter where Windows is installed.
2. Now look for `application.ini` file and open it in Wordpad.
3. At the end of the file, you'll see following lines:

   ```
   [Crash Reporter]
   Enabled=1
   ServerURL=https://crash-reports.mozilla.com/submit
   ```
4. Simply change the value of Enabled to 0 as following:

   ```
   [Crash Reporter]
   Enabled=0
   ServerURL=https://crash-reports.mozilla.com/submit
   ```
5. Save the file and now you'll no longer see the Crash reporter window.

Answer (score 0):

I have not seen this pop up for me since Firefox 2.0 or so, so this may not be completely applicable. I found [this](http://kb.mozillazine.org/Quality_Feedback_Agent) page about the feedback agent. If you are using an older version, this tells you where to find it and how to enable/disable it. Other than that, I believe it is an option in the installer to either enable or disable it.